# Email on Case feed minimized

Tags: servicecloud, casefeed

I have users working with Case and when they open a case and then assign the case to themselves the feed(email message) is being minimized - you can see this in the screen shot.

Only one line of the email conversation is being shown[image]

it is impossible to read then. The current work around is to refresh the page.

Can anything be done to prevent this, I'd like to prevent users from refreshing the page or is this is a standard behavior (obviously not useful for users as they have to refresh again)?